# How to test if the correct lambda value was passed as an argument (with Mockito)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, lambda, java-8, mockito

I have the function:

```
public class Cache {
    (...)
    public void removeAllIf(Predicate<Product> predicate) {
        (...)
    }
}
```

And I call `productsCache.removeAllIf(Product::isChecked);`

Currentlly I test it with

`then(productsCache).should().removeAllIf(any(Predicate.class));`

but this is not accurate (not testing if the passed lambda is `Product::isChecked`). The second problem is that I get the lint message: *Unchecked assignment*.

Is it better solution?

**Edited:**

I don't want to test `removeAllIf` function implementation. I want to test if `removeAllIf` was called with proper argument.

The scenario to test:

```
public class Repository {
    public void removeCheckedProducts() {
        remoteDataSource.removeCheckedProducts();
        localDataSource.removeCheckedProducts();
        cache.removeAllIf(Product::isChecked);

    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
@Test
public void removeCheckedProducts() {

    //when
    repository.removeCheckedProducts();

    //then
    then(remoteDataSource).should().removeCheckedProducts();
    then(localDataSource).should().removeCheckedProducts();
    then(cache).should().removeAllIf(any(Predicate.class));


}
```

Comment: Show me all your logic related to this scenario? The implementation of `removeAllIf` method and the predicate passed in with the structure of the `Product` class.

Comment: you should focus on the definition of `Product.isChecked` to unit test it.

Comment: I'm testing if `removeAllIf` was called, not the implementation of Product.isChecked. Please check my edit.

Comment: If the caller’s source code looks like `removeAllIf(Product::isChecked)`, it’s a waste of resource to write testing code to verify that this trivial piece of code truly invokes `removeAllIf` with the argument `Product::isChecked`. You should focus on testing whether the calling code does what it is supposed to do (okay, okay, if the caller is a method named `callTheMethodRemoveAllIfWithProductIsChecked` and its documentation says “*this method’s sole purpose is to call `removeAllIf` with the argument `Product::isChecked`*”, then, you’re on the right path).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArgumentCaptor

```
@Captor
  ArgumentCaptor<Predicate> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Predicate.class);;

@Test
public void removeCheckedProducts() {

    //when
    repository.removeCheckedProducts();

    //then
    then(remoteDataSource).should().removeCheckedProducts();
    then(localDataSource).should().removeCheckedProducts();
    then(cache).should().removeAllIf(captor.capture());
    Predicate t = Product.checkPredicate();
    assertSame(t,captor.getValue());



}
```

Comment: assertSame won't work, Object is not a functional interface.

Comment: Assign predicate into variable, and you can compare. Please be aware that to be able to compare predicate for equality you have to assign predicate into variable and reuse this predicate otherwise you will always create new Lambda. So the Product should have the method that always return the same predicate/lambda if you want to test for exact equality. If you cannot cache the lambda than you can check the toString of the lambda class and check if its from Product class.

Answer (score 0):

You could check removeAllIf argument behavior instead equality.

```
Predicate<Product> removeAllIfArgument = mockingDetails(cache).getInvocations()
        .iterator()
        .next()
        .getArgument(0);

Product checkedProduct = mock(Product.class);
Product uncheckedProduct = mock(Product.class);
given(checkedProduct.isChecked()).willReturn(true);
given(uncheckedProduct.isChecked()).willReturn(false);

assertTrue(removeAllIfArgument.test(checkedProduct));
assertFalse(removeAllIfArgument.test(uncheckedProduct));
```